# How to make css for overflow scroll bar

Tags: scrollbar, overflow

i am developing a website in simple html. I want to change the scroll bar design that shows default. Does any css for scroll bar to change color and other properties.

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
div 
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: you can format this as per your expectations like color and all those.

Answer (score 0):

Only webkit-based browsers (Google Chrome, Apple Safari, Opera) support scrollbar [CSS customization](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/). Firefox & IE do not support changing scrollbar design. To change scrollbar via CSS in all modern browsers, try to use custom scrollbar plugins, for example [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar).